# How to compute the syzygy subcategory of module categories?

Tags: ct.category-theory

Let A be a finite dimensional algebra, for module category A-mod, how to compute the syzygy subcategory of module categories?

I will study the properties of syzygy subcategories.

Can you give me some examples?

This question is similar with [How to check whether a module is an n-th syzygy](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/254453/how-to-check-whether-a-module-is-an-n-th-syzygy)

Thank you